# Revert BitBucket prematurely declaring a PR merged

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

In BitBucket I created a PR tracking a feature branch. In the process of rebasing (and pushing) the feature branch, BitBucket has registering the PR as merged. (That is, I must  have unintentionally pushed the wrong head to the feature branch, causing BitBucket to interpret an unrelated merge commit as the conclusion of the feature, and auto-close the PR.) So BitBucket is now linking the PR discussion to unrelated source changes, rather than displaying the current state of the feature branch).

Is there a way (*without modifying the main branch*) to revert the PR's autodetection of a putative merge, i.e., reopen the original PR as so that it resumes tracking the feature branch?

Note I'm happy with the state of both branches in the repo (I do not want to revert any merge commits on the main branch). I *could* just forget about this PR and open another PR tracking the feature branch again, but this would bury the existing discussion threads (and leave the BitBucket UI associating those threads with unrelated source changes). Rather than change the repo, I just want to fix the PR (which has accidentally started tracking an unrelated previously-merged change and stopped tracking the feature branch, which still contains commits that have *not* been merged) so that the discussion thread will be associated back to the appropriate source changes.